# IronPython - WPF window does not display, but not sure why

Tags: ironpython, visual-studio-community

I'm using IronPython in VS Community 2017. I'm having a weird problem that I don't understand, and I'm sure is simple but can't find anyone else having it, which is confusing me even more.

I have this very simple code to try to manipulate the value of text in a box defined in the xaml.

```
class MyWindow(Window):
  def __init__(self):
wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')    

win = MyWindow()
win.Test = win.FindName('test')
win.Test.Text = 'Hello, World'
Application().Run(win)
```

XAML

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  Title="WpfApplication1" Height="300" Width="420.408"> 
    <TextBox x:Name="Test" MinWidth="100" Margin="14,79,98,155"/>
</Window>
```

Obviously this doesn't do anything interesting yet, and I'm just trying to learn, but this very basic hangup doesn't make any sense to me.

*I wanted to separate the XAML from the python above but the editor on this site is beyond bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  Program was erroring out.  Not used to debugging in VS Community yet, not quite as intuitive as VBA which is what I'm the most used to.  I'm sure that might be due to default setup, trying to figure out how to get it to give a bit more feedback than it does, as I was going on the error list showing no errors which was obviously not right.

So the error was me attempting to assign win.FindName('test') to win.Test .  I had seen something like this on a site elsewhere, and had problems prior to this as well, so I wasn't sure what to try, but now I know I can do this several different ways

1) Test = win.FindName('Test')  (excluding the win. at the start)
    Test.Text = 'Hello, World'

Or, simpler

2) win.Test.Text = 'Hello, World'

I feel like I tried the 2nd one earlier, but it is working now so I'm sure something else was broken.

Current working code

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
  def __init__(self):
    wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')           

win = MyWindow()
Test = win.FindName('Test')
Test.Text = 'Hello, World'
Application().Run(win)
```

Comment: Have a slight correction on above as well, apparently win.Test = win.FindName('Test') is fine, it's just that everything is case sensitive, which is another thing I'm not quite so used to yet, coming from VBA, which tends not to have much of that.